# Add more than 1 column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri24E.jpg)

[Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgAVh.jpg)

I am a complete beginner. I built a simple database following a YouTube video and it works fine, then I wanted to add a search box, and this works following another YouTube video for one column only, my problem is how do I add other columns.

This is the script that works for 1 column

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:J,"SELECT * WHERE LOWER(E)= LOWER("""&B2&""")", 1)
```

If I change the E in (E) to one of the other columns it works, but when I try to add them altogether is doesn't

I would like the columns (E, F, G, H and J). I've never done anything like this before, its just for my movies and TV series, I wanted to search for keywords, etc, so if I wanted to look for just comedy then I could write comedy in the search box B2 and all the comedies would show up, etc.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your data, so that readers can understand the structure? An image upload tool is available in the editor.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is related to the use of the LOWER function when the value in the column is not just text but also includes numbers. To handle this, you can modify the formula to use LOWER only for text columns and leave it out for columns that contain numbers.

Here's an adjusted formula:

=QUERY(Data!A1:J, "SELECT * WHERE LOWER(E) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(F) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(G) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(H) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(J) = LOWER('"&B2&"')", 1)

In this modified formula, I've kept the LOWER function only for columns E, F, G, H, and J. If column E contains text and numbers, you might want to apply LOWER only to the text part of it, or you can remove LOWER altogether for such columns.

Try this adjustment, and it should help resolve the issue with the TV series "24" in your database.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't actually see a difference between the modified code and the original, I tried it anyway and the problem still exists. SO I then tried without lower but a different error came up.But thank you anyway for trying

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! The QUERY function in Google Sheets allows you to filter and manipulate data in various ways. In your case, you want to search across multiple columns. You can modify your formula to include multiple columns in the WHERE clause. Try it:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:J, "SELECT * WHERE LOWER(E) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(F) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(G) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(H) = LOWER('"&B2&"') OR LOWER(J) = LOWER('"&B2&"')", 1)
```

Break it down:

- `LOWER(E) = LOWER('"&B2&"')`: This checks if the value in column E matches the search term in B2 (case-insensitive).
- `OR`: This is used to combine multiple conditions.
- Repeat this pattern for other columns (F, G, H, J) as well.

This way, the formula will return rows where the search term in B2 matches any of the specified columns (E, F, G, H, or J).

Comment: It works thank you ever so much. I don't totally understand, but it works :D

Comment: thank you for you help, everything was working well until, I added the tv series 24 into the database. I get a "Unable to parse query string for function query parameter 2 lower takes a text parameter", I don't know enough to fix this myself, but I did alter 24 in the database to Twenty Four and that fixed it, but its not called Twenty Four its 24, can you advise